# File.Exists() works in one class, but not in the other, despite the code being duplicates

Tags: c#, windows

In my program I have to check, if a directory exists or not and when it doesn't the directory shall be created. I need that in two different classes. It works fine in the one, not at all in the other class. I could probably make this function a method and just call it in both places, but I was wondering how that can be.
So here's my code in class one:

```
string path = @"F:\yyyy\images\" + input+ "\\" + now + "\\";

if (!File.Exists(path))
{
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
}
```

Where "now" is a string, containing the current date and input is just another string.

Code in class two:

```
string path = @"F:\yyyy\images\" + command[2] + "\\" + now+ "\\";

if (!File.Exists(path))
{
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
}
```

The second example always runs, no matter if the directory exists or not.

`command[2]` is a string, basically being the same as "input" in the first example. To test if its really the same, I did this in class 2:

`System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path + 1);`

And it made a "1" directory, inside the directory, that class 1 just created.

Comment: Please, use Path.Combine() instead manual string concatination in path generation

Comment: FYI: there is no point in checking `Directory.Exists()` if you're just going to create the directory if it doesn't. Just call `CreateDirectory()`; if the directory already exists, it'll return without doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to find check if a directory exists, use [Directory.Exists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.exists?view=net-5.0) instead of `File.Exists`. Your `if` check is unnecessary though. The `Directory.Create` method already does this check.

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.createdirectory?view=net-5.0):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```csharp
if (!File.Exists(path))
{
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
}
```

You're checking to see if a file exists, and if it doesn't creating a directory with the name.  At the end of this activity, there is still no directory that exists.  What you want to do is see if the directory exists:

```csharp
string path = @"F:\yyyy\images\" + input + "\\" + now;
if (!Directory.Exists(path))
{
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
}
```

Also: Notice that I got rid of the trailing backslash.  It's not strictly necessary, and I tend to find it adds noise.

Answer (score 0):

you want to check if the directory exists or the file?

***Directory.Exists***

***File.Exists***